# JAX-RS External Service Library

Tags: web-applications, servlets, jersey, jax-rs, jsr311

I have a group of cut and paste JAX-RS 1.1.1 annotated classes that I share between 4 services.  These are management services that provide telemetry from process like hibernate and a common version info resource. In my web.xml I supply the fully qualifed name for the external packages, but they are not getting picked up.  Has anyone created a library of JAX-RS services and included them in disparate services?

My web.xml

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.mycompany.webserivce.rest.resource1;
               com.mycompany.webservice.rest.resource2;
               com.mycompany.webservice.rest.providers;
               com.mycompany.common.rest.stats;
  </param-value>
</init-param>
```

At runtime the log shows

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.mycompany.webserivce.rest.resource1;
  com.mycompany.webservice.rest.resource2;
  com.mycompany.webservice.rest.providers;
  com.mycompany.common.rest.stats;
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.mycompany.webserivce.rest.resource1.Resource1Resource;
  class com.mycompany.webserivce.rest.resource2.Resource2Resource;
INFO: Provider classes found:     
  class com.mycompany.webservice.rest.providers.Resource1XMLWriter;
  class com.mycompany.webservice.rest.providers.Resource2XMLWriter;
INFO: Initting jersey....
```

As you can see, the root resources from **com.mycompany.common.rest.stats** are not found.

Comment: OK, so my dumb arse added the common lib to the wrong pom.  Once it added it to the correct pom, it all worked.  Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I added the common lib to the wrong POM.  Once I added it to the correct POM it all worked.